# @media min-width is not overriding normal CSS?

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

my min-width is not overriding my normal CSS? I've not had this issue before but I just can't seem to get it working. Using "!important" doesn't help either.

Here's my code -

```
.slant-container {
  .test-container {
    .services-content {
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      align-items: center;
      text-align: left;
      justify-content: space-around;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;

      .left-hero {
        width: 100%;

        .hero-p {
          width: 100%;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 841px) {
  .slant-container {
    .test-container {
      .services-content {
        .left-hero {
          width: 50%;

          .hero-p {
            padding-bottom: 3rem;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the box display and just set the flex direction of the parent container `.services-content` like so:

```
.slant-container {
  .test-container {
    .services-content {
      align-items: center;
      text-align: left;
      justify-content: space-around;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;

      .left-hero {
        width: 100%;

        .hero-p {
          width: 100%;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 841px) {
  .slant-container {
    .test-container {
      .services-content {
        flex-direction: row;
        
        .left-hero {
          width: 50%;

          .hero-p {
            padding-bottom: 3rem;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This achieves roughly the same effect. To centrally align the element and achieve the boxed kind of effect you have on your smaller screen sizes for the `.left-hero` element you can do something like this:

```
.left-hero {
  ...
  .hero-p {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
  }
}
```

See [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/DannyXCII/pen/jOyXzzm) to visualise - snippets don't currently support SCSS (someone edit this if I'm wrong please).